# Read line from console without STD

Tags: c++, io

I can easily print line on console with `printf`. But how to read line without `std` library?

Comment: Why without the standard library?

Comment: `std` is what gives you a guarantee that it'll work across platforms. You're going to have to use platform specific functions if you don't want to use it.

Comment: `scanf` opposite of `printf`

Comment: The console might not exist. How about a program run (on Unix) with some redirection, or in batch mode (e.g. with `batch` or `at`)

Comment: `printf` is part of the `std` library.

Comment: `WINAPI ReadFile` or `read()` (Unix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using standardized methods, your code will be guaranteed to be portable across different platforms. Without that, you have to write code for every platform you want to target.

`printf` and `scanf`, `std::cout` and `std::cin` and `std::cerr` provides portable ways to write to stdout / read from stdin / write to stderr. If you want to avoid this, you may have to write to stdout in Windows with

```
HANDLE GetStdHandle(DWORD nStdHandle);
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
    HANDLE       hFile,
    LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
    DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
    LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
    LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

and in a POSIX-compliant system by using

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void* buf, size_t count);
```

You see, you can never port `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` to Unix, nor can you port `write` to Windows or another system (like Solaris). Even if you're eager to write wrapper functions, that would be way more suffering than using standardized libraries.

P.S. The `DWORD nStdHandle` WinAPI parameter is different from the `int fd` Unix API, the former [requires `-10`, `-11` and `-12` for stdin/stdout/stderr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle), respectively, while the latter requires 0, 1 and 2.

---

Even if you try to do something seemingly simple, you will end up doing extra work. For example:

Standardized:

```
#include<stdio.h>
printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
```

Unix:

```
#include <unistd.h>
// <stdio.h> and <string.h> is still needed.
char buf[64];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(char),
    "%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
ssize_t written =
  write(1, buf, strlen(buf));
```

Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
char buf[64];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(char),
    "%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a+b);
HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD dwWritten;
BOOL failed = WriteFile(
    hOutput, buf, strlen(buf), &dwWritten, NULL
);
```

Actually you have to parse the string by yourself if you don't want to use standard functions. I used `snprintf`/`strlen` for easy illustration but surely that's some extra work.

Answer (score 0):

The Standard Library provides methods that are guaranteed to be cross platform, thus is adviced to use it.

If you didn't you would need to write specific code which targets a platform.

For example, if you want to target Linux, then you would use [`read()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> read from a file descriptor